# Synergy with a Macbook Laptop with Sony laptop

Tags: windows-xp, macbook, synergy

Can you connect synergy with a Macbook with a Sony laptop with synergy and have the macbook be the server computer and the Sony be the client?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,
just be sure to tell `synergy` (on each computer) whether it's a server or a client.